# Convert an image RGB->Lab with python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-imaging-library, color-space

What is the preferred way of doing the conversion using PIL/Numpy/SciPy today?

Comment: I've read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228361/using-pil-and-numpy-to-convert-an-image-to-lab-array-modify-the-values-and-then and it gives a broken link to a color.py which is missing from scipy trunk.

Comment: Yes, I've found this file deep in the scipy git repository, but I can't beleive there's no standard way of doing such a simple thing using such powerful tools.

Comment: And yes, I know about code.google.com/p/python-colormath lib, and yet I can't understand why didn't it make its way into any of those three tools.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Since 2010 when the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228361/using-pil-and-numpy-to-convert-an-image-to-lab-array-modify-the-values-and-then) was asked the corresponding code moved from scipy to a separate toolkit:
http://scikit-image.org/

So here's the code I was actually looking for:

```
from skimage import io, color
rgb = io.imread(filename)
lab = color.rgb2lab(rgb)
```

It should also be noted that due to [Lab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space) nature srgb->lab conversion depends on an additional parameter: *whitepoint*, eg:
   • **Photoshop** uses a white point called D50 (which is a standard for icc)
   • **OpenCV** and skimage use D65 (which is a standard for srgb).
   • default **Matlab** implementation uses D50 (it is capable of using [others](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/whitepoint.html)),

This nice [FAQ](http://www.poynton.com/ColorFAQ.html) explains it this way:

> You should use D65 unless you have a good reason to use something
>   else.
>   The print industry commonly uses D50 and photography commonly
>   uses D55.
>   These represent compromises between the conditions of indoor
>   (tungsten) and daylight viewing.

You can tell which whitepoint you're dealing with by converting RGB `(0,0,255)` to Lab:
   • D50 would give you (30, 68, -112)
   • D55                            (30, 73, -110)
   • D65                          (32, 79, -108)

The numbers after 'D' correspond to (internally) used color temperature of white point: D50 = 5003 K (yellowish), D65 = 6504 K (blueish)

I'm grateful to Alex and Roman for their answers because they pointed me into the right direction.

Comment: In `skimage` you can change white point to D50 or something else http://stackoverflow.com/a/22968744/2863099

Comment: D50=yellowish and D65=bluish are the correct acronyms I believe

Answer (score 36):

I've found this code on the old [Adobe Cookbook site](https://web.archive.org/web/20120502065620/http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Useful_color_equations__RGB_to_LAB_converter-14227.html) and have adapted for Python. It doesn't require any third-party modules or components:

```
def rgb2lab ( inputColor ) :

   num = 0
   RGB = [0, 0, 0]

   for value in inputColor :
       value = float(value) / 255

       if value > 0.04045 :
           value = ( ( value + 0.055 ) / 1.055 ) ** 2.4
       else :
           value = value / 12.92

       RGB[num] = value * 100
       num = num + 1

   XYZ = [0, 0, 0,]

   X = RGB [0] * 0.4124 + RGB [1] * 0.3576 + RGB [2] * 0.1805
   Y = RGB [0] * 0.2126 + RGB [1] * 0.7152 + RGB [2] * 0.0722
   Z = RGB [0] * 0.0193 + RGB [1] * 0.1192 + RGB [2] * 0.9505
   XYZ[ 0 ] = round( X, 4 )
   XYZ[ 1 ] = round( Y, 4 )
   XYZ[ 2 ] = round( Z, 4 )

   XYZ[ 0 ] = float( XYZ[ 0 ] ) / 95.047         # ref_X =  95.047   Observer= 2°, Illuminant= D65
   XYZ[ 1 ] = float( XYZ[ 1 ] ) / 100.0          # ref_Y = 100.000
   XYZ[ 2 ] = float( XYZ[ 2 ] ) / 108.883        # ref_Z = 108.883

   num = 0
   for value in XYZ :

       if value > 0.008856 :
           value = value ** ( 0.3333333333333333 )
       else :
           value = ( 7.787 * value ) + ( 16 / 116 )

       XYZ[num] = value
       num = num + 1

   Lab = [0, 0, 0]

   L = ( 116 * XYZ[ 1 ] ) - 16
   a = 500 * ( XYZ[ 0 ] - XYZ[ 1 ] )
   b = 200 * ( XYZ[ 1 ] - XYZ[ 2 ] )

   Lab [ 0 ] = round( L, 4 )
   Lab [ 1 ] = round( a, 4 )
   Lab [ 2 ] = round( b, 4 )

   return Lab
```

Comment: It doesn't directly answer the question: I needed a one-liner. But it is helpful anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Although I would reference the original [easyrgb](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH) site instead of the adobe cookbook.

Comment: Your code is not quite pythonic should I say. At the very least I'd use `enumerate` instead of the `num` variable and `1/3.` instead of `0.3333333333333333`

Comment: This code appears to do gamma correction ( `** 2.4` ).  What if I know my gamma is 2.2, not 2.4?  Is it enough to change the exponent to 2.2, or are changes needed to other hard-coded constants (like the 1.055)  ?

Comment: @jez the gamma 2.4 you see here is the sRGB standard. It joins together with a linear conversion at the lower values, and together they closely match a 2.2 gamma curve. I wouldn't change anything.

Comment: Thank you for working out this, I've tried a few values and they match those on http://colormine.org/convert/rgb-to-lab

Answer (score 8):

Edit: Sample pyCMS code:

```
from PIL import Image
import pyCMS
im = Image.open(...)
im2 = pyCMS.profileToProfile(im, pyCMS.createProfile("sRGB"), pyCMS.createProfile("LAB"))
```

Edit: Pillow, the PIL fork, seems to have pyCMS built in.

You might use pyCMS (http://www.cazabon.com/pyCMS/) which works with PIL images.

If speed is not a factor, use python-colormath (http://code.google.com/p/python-colormath/).

Comment: `pyCMS` deals with ICC profiles, color spaces are "side-effect". I asked for a one-liner.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned python-colormath in my third comment to the question.

Comment: Anthony, however you are correct that it is not a single matrix, because the xyz->lab transform is defined differently in different ranges of xyz.  Well, I don't think there's a one-liner, short of porting the relevant part of colormath to numpy first :)

Comment: The question is not *if* there is a one-liner (two were given in my comments to the question) but rather *why* neither of those two found its way into PIL/numpy/scipy *or* if there're some better alternatives.

Comment: Also there's no need in 'porting' colormath to numpy as it uses numpy since its inception.

Comment: If you give an example of using pyCMS for this conversion, I shall accept your answer.

Comment: I'd delete the last part pertaining to PIL-only solution since it is incorrect.

Comment: pyCMS looks good but using it is risky -- seems it will not be well maintained.

Comment: After some research I significantly improved my answer and I feel that it should be accepted now. I compensated your reputation ;)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a class, for transforming RGB<->LAB color spaces for PIL images:

```
from PIL import ImageCms

class ColorTrans:

    '''Class for transforming RGB<->LAB color spaces for PIL images.'''
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.srgb_p = ImageCms.createProfile("sRGB")
        self.lab_p  = ImageCms.createProfile("LAB")
        self.rgb2lab_trans = ImageCms.buildTransformFromOpenProfiles(srgb_p, lab_p, "RGB", "LAB")
        self.lab2rgb_trans = ImageCms.buildTransformFromOpenProfiles(lab_p, srgb_p, "LAB", "RGB")
    
    def rgb2lab(self, img):
        return ImageCms.applyTransform(img, self.rgb2lab_trans)

    def lab2rgb(self, img):
        return ImageCms.applyTransform(img, self.lab2rgb_trans)
```

Sample usage:

```
color_trans = ColorTrans()
c_img = Image.open(FILENAME)
c_img_lab = color_trans.rgb2lab(c_img)
c_img_rgb = color_trans.lab2rgb(c_img_lab)
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I haven't found a good package to do that. You have to bear in mind that RGB is a device-dependent colour space so you can't convert accurately to XYZ or CIE Lab if you don't have a profile.

So be aware that many solutions where you see converting from RGB to CIE Lab without specifying the colour space or importing a colour profile must be carefully evaluated. Take a look at the code under the hood most of the time they assume that you are dealing with sRGB colour space.