# Fast way to convert rgb to lab in python

Tags: python, colors, scikit-image

Is there a quick way to convert RGB to LAB in Python3 using D50 sRGB?

[Python-Colormath](https://github.com/gtaylor/python-colormath) too slow

[skimage](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.9.x/api/skimage.color.html#xyz2lab) use D65

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now, the white reference in skimage cannot be passed as a parameter (pull request welcome), but here is a workaround:

```
from skimage import color
color.colorconv.lab_ref_white = np.array([0.96422, 1.0, 0.82521])
lab = color.rgb2lab(image)
```

Comment: Thanks! But it works only for xyz2lab. For rgb2xyz should also be replaced `color.colorconv.xyz_from_rgb` according to [this](http://brucelindbloom.com/Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html) and it works. Thanks again for reference!

PS I am new to Python and am not sure I could handle with correct pull request. ))

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using D50?

Comment: I measured DMC floss colors with D50 source light, so i am using D50 for deltaE calculation when deal with RGB pictures. For example, warm white in DMC is `B5200` floss with lab(91.6, 1.5, -6.3). But in D65 lab(91.6, 1.5, -6.3) is cold white

Answer (score 3):

Stefan van der Walt's answer was correct at the time, but for anyone who still has the same question and finds this page: as of scikit-image 0.13 (Dec 2016), `skimage.color.rgb2lab` takes an `illuminant` parameter, so you can just write

`lab = color.rgb2lab(image, illuminant='D50')`