# How to convert a numpy array of RGB values to LAB values with colormath.color_conversions without using loops?

Tags: python, colors, computer-vision

I'm converting RGB triplets to LAB in this way.

```
from colormath.color_objects import sRGBColor, LabColor
from colormath.color_conversions import convert_color

for p in range(0,h):
    for q in range(0,w):
        rgb_color = sRGBColor(img_arr[p][q][0],img_arr[p][q][1],img_arr[p][q][2])
        lab_color = convert_color(rgb_color, LabColor)
```

But this method is slow. Is there a way I can convert `img_arr` from RGB to LAB without loops? I want to use `colormath` only.

Comment: Not sure if you can do much better with or without loops in this case, as the conversion functions dominate the spent time.

Comment: Even though you state that you want to use `colormath` only, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405956/convert-an-image-rgb-lab-with-python. Much much faster.

Comment: I've seen this link before.

Comment: @HarshWardhan: Colormath is not vectorised, so you can't get much speed from it, is it a strong requirement or would an alternative Python library work for you? https://github.com/colour-science/colour should cover pretty much everything colormath does but in a vectorised way, thus order of magnitude faster.