# skimage color space conversions turn image to static

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm using sci-kits module skimage to convert an image from RGB colorspace to LAB and back again. I found the following functions from this question: [Convert an image RGB->Lab with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405956/convert-an-image-rgb-lab-with-python), but this does not address how an image could be reduced to static.

Code:

```
file = 'C://Users/Alec/Pictures/25 zone test.png'
pix = numpy.array(PIL.Image.open(file))
print(pix[0,0])
pix = color.rgb2lab(pix)
print(pix[0,0])
pix = color.lab2rgb(pix)
print(pix[0,0])
pix *= 255
print(pix[0,0])
pix = pix.astype(int)
print(pix[0,0])
pic = PIL.Image.fromarray(pix, 'RGB')
pic.show()
```

Output:

```
[255 255 255]
[  1.00000000e+02  -2.45493786e-03   4.65342115e-03]
[ 1.  1.  1.]
[ 255.  255.  255.]
[255 254 254]
```

The output of the print statements seems more or less appropriate, however, the resulting image certainly is not.

Is there a step that I'm missing for this to work?

Original Image:

[image: Original Image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert an image RGB->Lab with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405956/convert-an-image-rgb-lab-with-python)

Comment: You are doing some weird stuff like multiplying by 255 and then overwriting it in the next line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This round-trip conversion gives me back the original image (or something very close):

```
from skimage import io, color
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = io.imread('/tmp/colors.png')
lab = color.rgb2lab(image)
rgb = color.lab2rgb(lab)

plt.imshow(rgb)
plt.show()
```

Comment: There must be an issue with the way PIL displays the image. Using pyplot worded!

Comment: But in your code this assertion would fail: `assert (image == rgb).all()`.

Comment: Yes, the ranges are different.  The following would succeed: np.allclose(util.img_as_float(image), util.img_as_float(rgb))