# Converting single value colors to LAB using python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, colors, cielab

I have an numpy array containing a single pixel/color in floating point RGB. I need to convert this value to LAB, for which I am trying the following:

`color = cv2.cvtColor(color.reshape((1,1,3)), cv2.COLOR_RGB2LAB).reshape((3))`

Where color is:
`array([137.38841, 161.38841,  65.38841], dtype=float32)`

The resulting LAB is: `[100.   0.   0.]`

Which clearly isn;t correct as it should be close to: `[62.667494977600484, 22.98637993404601, 46.1397720707445]`

How do I convert the value to LAB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were not reshaping it properly. Use the below code to do that.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
bgr = [40, 158, 16]
lab = cv2.cvtColor( np.uint8([[bgr]] ), cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)[0][0]
print(lab)  #[145  71 177]
```

Above code will help of rgb/bgr value is in integer. Since your values are in floating-point, I suggest you go with rgbtolab function found on this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16020102/9320324

Comment: at least in 2023, `cvtColor()` will accept normalized `np.float` arrays of colors. The result of a float array is the actual lab colors you'd expect (L in 0 to 100, a & b in -128 to 128).

Answer (score 0):

Here I am doing something similar, where I am translating the matplotlib xkcd colors into a LAB/name dict.

```
import matplotlib.colors as mc
import numpy as np
import cv2

cut = dict()
for name in mc.XKCD_COLORS:
    rgb = mc.to_rgb(mc.XKCD_COLORS[name])
    lab = cv2.cvtColor(np.single([[rgb]]), cv2.COLOR_RGB2Lab)[0][0]
    clut[tuple(lab)] = name[5:]
```