# Conversion RGB into LAB for multiple values

Tags: python, numpy, colors, rgb, cielab

I wrote a code that gives me the average RGB value of an image. Now I want besides the RGB value, also a LAB value. I found a code to do the conversion, but when I run the code, it only gives me the last value.

So with this code I receive the average RGB and place it in a dataframe:

```
import cv2 as cv
import glob
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
import pandas as pd
from colormath.color_objects import sRGBColor, LabColor
from colormath.color_conversions import convert_color

path = "image.jpg"
img_number = 1

for file in glob.glob(path):
    print(file)
    img = cv.imread(file)
    scale_percent = 60
    width = int(img.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
    height = int(img.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
    dim = (width, height)
    imgr = cv.resize(img, dim, interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)

    hsv = cv.cvtColor(imgr, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    blur0 = cv.medianBlur(hsv, 11)

    low_yellow = np.array([10, 42, 220])
    high_yellow = np.array([30, 255, 255])

    mask = cv.inRange(blur0, low_yellow, high_yellow)
    res = cv.bitwise_and(imgr, imgr, mask=mask)

    cv.imwrite("image"+str(img_number)+".jpg", res)
    img_number +=1


path1 = "Image/*.jpg"
img_number = 1

result_df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in glob.glob(path1):
    image = io.imread(file)
    x = image[np.all(image != 0, axis=2)].mean(axis=0)
    result_df = pd.concat((result_df, pd.DataFrame(x)), axis=1)
    df_t = result_df.T
    df_lab = rgb_to_cielab(df_t)
    df_t.columns = ['R', 'G', 'B']
    df_t.loc['Mean'] = df_t.mean()

    df = df_t.round(decimals=1)
df.to_excel("Excel.xlsx")
```

When I want to converse my RGB value to LAB I found this code to do the conversion:

```
def rgb_to_cielab(a):
"""
a is a pixel with RGB coloring
"""
a1,a2,a3 = a/255

color1_rgb = sRGBColor(a1, a2, a3);

color1_lab = convert_color(color1_rgb, LabColor);

return color1_lab
```

When I run this code it provides me only the last value. I quite sure I am creating a loop, but I don't know how to fix it. Can someone help me with this?

I know my title is a bit different as my real question but maybe someone knows a easier way to get the LAB values?

Comment: what is the shape of `x`? what does the `sRGBColor` return? what is the `LabColor`?

Comment: please add the imports (basically make your code reproducible to get help)

Comment: To be honest, I fountd the def rgb_to_cielab(a) code here in an other question. I tested it and it works for me. Except it gives me only the LAB value of the last RGB.  the x gives me a R, G and B value @alex

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert an image RGB->Lab with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405956/convert-an-image-rgb-lab-with-python)

Comment: @PeterO. I believe it doesn't because my answer was not accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405956/convert-an-image-rgb-lab-with-python) question (possible duplicate).

More details on the [official documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html?highlight=color#skimage.color.rgb2lab).

**Long Answer**

Use these formula to get your own conversion.

1. [RGB => XYZ](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_to_XYZ.html)
2. [XYZ => Lab](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_XYZ_to_Lab.html)

Please keep in mind that there is not a single Lab (depending on the CIE you use), so you might want to tweak the values if necessary.